# Why does Scala script not find classes despite setting CLASSPATH or using -classpath option?

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala (2.10.1) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLASSPATH=${WORKSPACE}/build/classes/main:${WORKSPACE}/build/libs/setter-for-catan.jar

exec ${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala "$0" "$@" 2>&1
!#

import sfc.board.SmallBoard
```

and:

```
$ cd ${WORKSPACE}
$ find build/classes/main -name 'SmallBoard*.class'
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$1.class
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$2.class
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$3.class
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$4.class
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$5.class
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$6.class
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard$.class
build/classes/main/sfc/board/SmallBoard.class
$ jar tvf build/libs/setter-for-catan.jar | grep SmallBoard
  1272 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$1.class
  1272 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$2.class
  1276 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$3.class
  1581 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$4.class
  1103 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$5.class
  1527 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard$$anonfun$6.class
  8097 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard$.class
  3722 Sun Jun 30 20:40:54 EDT 2013 sfc/board/SmallBoard.class
```

yet the script isn't finding the sfc package much less the class:

```
$ ./setter-for-catan.scala 
./setter-for-catan.scala:10: error: not found: object sfc
import sfc.board.SmallBoard
       ^
one error found
```

What's going on and what needs to be done to fix it?

Comment: Explain please, what does "!#" operator mean? It's hard to find in search engines.

Comment: Try to use `scala -cp your-classpath`.

Comment: @red1ynx, !# ends a multi-line shebang in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scala -cp ${CLASSPATH}`, not `scala -classpath ${CLASSPATH}`.